# com.google.android.maps doesn't exist in Android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, android-studio

I am getting a com.google.android.maps does not exist error on compile.

But in Eclipse I could use the `maps` lib in `F:\backup e\Software\Android Eclipse\bundle\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-19\libs`.So it doesn't throw the compile error.

But in Android Studio,I don't know how to add the maps lib properly.I have added the maps lib directly to studio but it didn't worked for me.

**Gradle Build:**

```
 error: package com.google.android.maps does not exist
 error: package com.google.android.maps does not exist
 error: cannot find symbol class Overlay
 error: cannot find symbol class MapView
 error: cannot find symbol class MapView
 error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
 error: cannot find symbol variable super
```

**RouteOverlay.java:**

```
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;

public class RouteOverlay extends Overlay {

 @Override
    public final void draw(final Canvas canvas, final MapView mapView, final boolean shadow) {
    super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

}
}
```

**build.gradle:**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.9.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.2.0.jar')


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:2.4.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.1'
}
```

Anyone can help me with this.Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you don't have installed Google Play Services from SDK manager, can you check this?

Comment: @helbaroudy everything installed.

Comment: I see that you include com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0, but you can't use it with your RouteOverlay class. So just remove this class. And if you will have problems, come here, there are new ways to show routes (PolylineOptions)

Answer (score 1):

MapOverlay etc does not supporting in google maps v2.

U have to use default MapFragment

Comment: No. it is working in eclipse not in studio.Because of library issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are using old code for Google Maps API v1.
the packages are now a bit different:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/package-summary

follow the guide in this (and the other pages on the left, not only this link!):
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/config

Comment: What I have to do to overcome this issue.But only this codes solved my requirement.

Comment: sorry, I did not get your question. The "Overlay" class and the package "com.google.android.maps" are old and refers to Version 1 of google maps api. In android studio (and more in general in android) Version1 is deprecated and no longer available so you have to migrate the code. There is no such mapping 1-1 for every class or procedure, so you have to elaborate a bit more the code.

Comment: That is google map v2 .I had referred this [tutorial](http://prashantandroid.blogspot.in/2014/05/display-route-in-google-maps-api-v2-on.html)